# Node cluster versus Dynos scaling

Tags: node.js, heroku, scalability

After reading a handful of articles on scaling node apps I have not yet made up my mind about when should I use node builtin cluster or simply adding more dynos.

Let me tell you I have already read the following threads on StackOverflow:

[How to properly scale nodejs app on heroku using clusters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616813/how-to-properly-scale-nodejs-app-on-heroku-using-clusters)

[Running Node.js App with cluster module is meaningless in Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410226/running-node-js-app-with-cluster-module-is-meaningless-in-heroku)

As far as I understood it, if I make use of node cluster functionality I will end up with the total memory available divided by the number of forked processes.

On the other hand, if I add one more dyno I will double the memory available.

So, what is the point of using node clusters?

Answer (score 3):

It's not really an either-or situation. You can make use of multiple node cluster instances on multiple dynos. Memory isn't really what you want to look at, though, since that would be a shared resource. CPU / core usage is more relevant to clustering in node, since each node process can only make use of one CPU core at a time.

It's really going to depend on which dynos you are using, too.

Have you seen [these suggestions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-concurrency) on the official heroku docs yet?

Comment: Yeah, those crazy docs.... In Heroku's case, very well written and mandatory reading for folks using their stuff, imo

Comment: @dvlsg, well, it was precisely after reading that document that I thought one should not look at CPUs but at RAM held by the dyno. But for instance, if I am using the free account, i.e., a dyno featuring 512 MB of memory, there is no point in using clustering, right?

Comment: No, you would still want to look at the CPUs / cores in most cases. But if you are using the free dynos (or hobby or standard-1x), your conclusion is still correct. You would only want to use one instance of your node application, because only one core is made available to you. The [defaults table](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-concurrency#tuning-the-concurrency-level) and number of cluster workers is what you want to look at here.

Comment: Well, I might be misunderstanding it, but according to that table they say only after clustering more than 1 worker will hurt the application. So, they advise clustering even for free, hobby, standard-1x dynos. Am i right?

Comment: No, the way I'm reading it (and I think I'm reading it correctly), is that they are suggesting 1 worker for the free / hobby / 1x dynos, which is more-or-less the same as just having a single process without the overhead of worrying about clustering, since you know you intend on just having a single process anyways.

Comment: Thanks, dvlsg for your clarification.